# laravel Using multiple whereIn to filter out a product from table

Tags: php, laravel

This is my table **Variation**

```
+---------------+---------+------------+-----------+--------+---------+----------+
|  product_id   | sku_id  | option_id  | value_id  |  sku   | option  |  value   |
+---------------+---------+------------+-----------+--------+---------+----------+
|           18  |     11  |         7  |        7  | wsu34  | size    | 7        |
|           18  |     11  |         8  |        8  | wsu34  | color   | #2A2947  |
|           18  |     12  |         7  |        9  | ws52   | size    | 5        |
|           18  |     12  |         8  |       10  | ws52   | color   | #64556d  |
|           18  |     13  |         7  |       11  | wsu34  | size    | 10       |
|           18  |     13  |         8  |       12  | wsu34  | color   | #64556d  |
+---------------+---------+------------+-----------+--------+---------+----------+
```

I want to pick a product by filtering the columns 'option' and 'value'

```
$opt = [size", "color"];
$val = ["5", "#2A2947"];

$kf = Variation::whereIn('option', $opt)
             ->whereIn('value',$val)->where('product_id', 18)
             ->pluck('sku');
```

The sql query was

> "select * from `variations` where `option` in (?, ?) and `value` in
>   (?, ?)"

The desired result was supposed to be **wsu34**

But I was getting the wrong values.

**edit**

differnt query with

```
  $opt = [size", "color"];
  $val = ["10", "#64556d"];

$kf = Variation::whereIn('option', $opt)
->whereIn('value',$val)
->where('product_id',$prodId)
->pluck('sku')
->toArray();
```

the result = [
"ws52",
"wsu34",
"wsu34"
]

Comment: Your code has sintax errors with missing quotes. Is that the real code?

Comment: Going by your provided code, the query would return two different SKUs, not one.

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: what is your desired result?

Comment: $opt = ["size", "color"]; value_id = 10,11,12, so is correct, any problems ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The desired result was supposed to be wsu34".

It sounds like your query isn't what you want, because you're trying to SELECT ONLY ONE sku based on all the conditions, but your query is returning matches on product_id_TO_opt_id OR product_id_TO_value_id.

But I think what you actually want is matching on product_id_TO_opt_id AND product_id_TO_value_id. As your query is currently written, BOTH the value and column don't have to match all 3 conditions they just have to match in either column and the product_id.

To fix this,  you'll have to change your query to check *4 specific conditions of matching between your 4 criteria for option and value* -- like this in raw SQL:

```
SELECT
    v.sku
FROM (
  SELECT
    product_id, sku_id, sku, opt, val
  FROM variation
  WHERE product_id = 18
) v
WHERE (v.val = "10" AND v.opt = "size") OR (v.val = "10" AND v.opt = "color")
  OR (v.val = "#64556d" AND v.opt = "size") OR (v.val = "#64556d" AND v.opt = "size");
```

[SQL Fiddle - returns just "wsu34"](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da5e70/28)

As for doing this in Laravel 4/5, I'd suggest trying a raw or DB-select query OR just adding each of those above as a new ->where() condition.

```
DB::select(...)

DB:raw(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

i test your code . your query return :

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "wsu34"
  1 => "ws52"
]
```

Because the first and third rows match your queries.

To see the query, you can create an error in the query and see your query on the debug page.
For example, I replaced ‍`sku` with `sku1`:

```
$opt = ['size', "color"];
$val = ["5", "#2A2947"];


$kf = Variation::whereIn('option', $opt)
    ->whereIn('value',$val)->where('product_id', 18)->pluck("sku1");
    dd($kf->toArray());
```

And on the debug page, **your query** will show you .

```
select `sku` from `variation` where `option` in (size, color) and `value` in (5, #2A2947) and `product_id` = 18.
```

[image]

---

---

## update

if you want only return `wsu34` . you can use this query :

```
SELECT 
`sku1`
FROM
    `variation`
WHERE
    `product_id` = 18 AND `option` = 'color'
        AND `value` IN ('#64556d')
        AND `sku` IN (SELECT 
            `sku`
        FROM
            `variation`
        WHERE
            `option` = 'size' AND `value` IN (10))
```

in this way :

```
$size=['10'];
$color=["#64556d"];

$kf = Variation::where('product_id',18)->where('option', 'color')->whereIn('value', $color)->whereIn('sku',function ($query) use ($size) {
$query->select('sku')
    ->from(with(new Variation)->getTable())
    ->where('option', 'size')->whereIn('value', $size);
    })
->pluck('sku')
->toArray();

dd($kf);
```

Comment: I test the second query and it was OK. it returns  `array:3 [▼
  0 => "ws52"
  1 => "wsu34"
  2 => "wsu34"
]`. what is your problem exactly ?

Comment: I want it to only return 'wsu34' since it only it has 'color' is '#64556d' and 'size' is '10', 'ws52' matches neither